# T-SQL - Equal to both but not either

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to write a simple query where each ID needs to have both Product A AND B but not either. In my example, I only want ID #3 and the Product's of each to return as none of the other ID's will fit this criteria.

I've taken a look at Count/ Rank/ Row_Number and can't seem to figure this one out.  Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way. Any ideas?

```
 ID Product 
 1  A
 2  A
 3  A
 3  A
 3  B
 4  A
 5  B
 6  B
 6  B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `group by` and `having`.

```
select id 
from tbl 
where product in ('A','B')
group by id
having count(distinct product) = 2
```

Comment: That works with only the ID column but not adding in the Product and a couple other columns in the select. Could I just take this and put it into a sub select and then inner join only on the results from your query?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 products, you can self-join your table:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Product, B.Product FROM [table] A INNER JOIN [table] B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Product != B.Product
```